# ASP.NET MVC LINQ Entity Framework remove isn't working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

heres my code:

```
User user = db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == userInSession.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            UserItem UI = user.UserItems.Where(ui => ui.User == user && ui.Item == item&& ui.IsFavourite == true).FirstOrDefault();
            if (UI == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                user.UserItems.Remove(UI);
                return true;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
```

It's finds the erntry and tries to remove it, but after removing it, it doesn't delete the entire row, it just deletes the value of UserID in the table. What am I missing here? When I do .Add it works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `db.UserItems.Remove` to remove the actual object. Also you can create a single query to check if the UserItems exists for that specific userSessionId as below :

```
var UI = db.UserItems.Where(ui => ui.User.ID == userInSession.ID && ui.Item == item && ui.IsFavourite == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're code is doing there is removing the *mapping* from the user item to the user.  You'll have to remove the user item with the data context you're using.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save I have a db.SaveChanges after I'll update my code

Comment: I only really want to delete UserItems by going user.UserItems.remove() otherwise I have to add my UserItems to the db context?? Was hoping EF would handle it

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to add the UserItems in the db context ?

Comment: Not really.... I just think its cleaning to be able to go user.items.remove() rather than getting the item first from the user, then using that to delete from the other collection. Oh well, if that is what I ahve to do.. then Ill have to do it!

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Deletes in EF are a lot more of a pain that inserts :(